# Navigate to first diff in diff mode on startup?

Tags: cursor-movement, vimdiff, autocmd

Vim diff opens 2 files for diffing, but it doesn't navigate to the first diff section automatically on startup. Can I add something to startup script (like _vimrc) to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "navigate to the first diff"?

Comment: I mean jump to the first diff section, like command `]c` does.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`]c` doesn't jump to the *first* difference, it jumps to the *next* difference. If your first difference is on the first line, `]c` would jump to the the second one which is not what you want. One could work around that with `]c[c` (jump to next difference then jump to previous).

This command:

```
$ vim -d -c 'norm ]c[c' filea fileb
```

seems to do what you want.

I don't think it is necessarily a good idea to put that in your startup sciript.

Comment: You could put that as an autocommand only when `'diff'` is on, I suppose. That seems harmless enough... `:help vimdiff` gives an example of how (`if &diff`)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, building on @romainl's answer:

```
if &diff
  " Jump to next change, then prev change. This puts us on the first change
  " even if it is on line 1.
  autocmd VimEnter * normal! ]c[c
endif
```

This needs to be on `VimEnter` (I'm not sure why neither `BufReadPost` or `BufEnter` work, maybe someone else knows?) I used the script linked [in this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/what-is-the-order-of-winenter-bufenter-bufread-syntax-filetype-events) to determine the earliest event that will work correctly.

You can also add other diff-only mappings in the same block:

```
  " Jump to next change after getting or putting a chunk
  nnoremap do <Cmd>diffget<CR>]c
  nnoremap dp <Cmd>diffput<CR>]c
```