# What is the order of WinEnter, BufEnter, BufRead, Syntax, FileType events?

Tags: buffers, vim-windows, autocmd

I've gone through the `autocmd.txt` help, but the information about this is scattered and not always present (eg. with `BufRead`).

Could someone who understands this well list the order of these events - with perhaps the conditions marked in parantheses, like

```
WinEnter   
BufEnter (if this window is for a different buffer than the current)
```

and so on, for easy reference?

Note <sup>(copied from my own comment below)</sup>:  I'm not talking about individual explanations of them, which are OK, but about how they interact with one another and in what order they happen. For eg., `WinEnter` says "Vim executes the BufEnter autocommands after the WinEnter autocommands", `TabEnter` says "After triggering the WinEnter and before triggering the BufEnter event", it's all scattered like this into many places. And sometimes it's not mentioned at all (for eg. `BufRead` doesn't mention whether it runs after BufEnter or before - maybe an expert can infer it from some other piece of info there, but I can't.
So, my intent here is to create a single, simple reference for the order of these events that can be looked up quickly by non-experts, in order to be more precise in our `autocmd` event specifications.

Comment: I think most of the explanations are OK, can you give a list of the ones you cannot understand ?

Comment: @Nobe4 I'm not talking about individual explanations of them, which are indeed OK, but about how they interact with one another and in what order they happen. For eg., `WinEnter` says "Vim executes the BufEnter autocommands after the WinEnter autocommands", `TabEnter` says "After triggering the WinEnter and before triggering the BufEnter event", it's all scattered like this into many places. And sometimes it's not mentioned at all (for eg. `BufRead` doesn't mention whether it runs after BufEnter or before - maybe an expert can infer it from some other piece of info there, but I can't.

Comment: So, my intent here is to create a single, simple reference for the order of these events that can be looked up quickly by non-experts, in order to be more precise in our `autocmd` event specifications.

Comment: OK I didnt understand the question. You can try to log every event, and see the order of appearance (I can make an answer if you like)

Comment: Your intent is actually to ask about somebody providing such a simple reference, not create one (yourself) ;)

Comment: @VanLaser yes, because I don't have the expertise to understand the intricacies of it, and will probably mess it up and provide wrong information in the attempt. Better to leave it to the experts!

Comment: I think creating such a reference is a great idea and should benefit from the community participation, so maybe you should head for a "real" project (maybe a github with a fancy github page) rather than a vi.SE question... Also even if you think you are not an expert, you can start scratching the surface of how it's work. You can log all events from vim, and start your study from there. As no reference exists it can be a great thing to start one :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I tried googling for this with different sets of keywords, and struck gold on one such attempt with this result:
https://web.archive.org/web/20220121051339/https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-vim-script-5/

Specifically, this part is relevant to the current question:

> For example, if you start Vim, edit a file named demo.txt, swap into Insert mode, type in some text, save the file, and then exit, your Vim session receives a series of events like what is shown in Listing 1.
>
> Listing 1. Event sequence in a simple Vim editing session
>
> > vim
>
> 1. BufWinEnter     (create a default window)
> 2. BufEnter        (create a default buffer)
> 3. VimEnter        (start the Vim session)**:edit demo.txt**
> 4. BufNew          (create a new buffer to contain demo.txt)
> 5. BufAdd          (add that new buffer to the session’s buffer list)
> 6. BufLeave        (exit the default buffer)
> 7. BufWinLeave     (exit the default window)
> 8. BufUnload       (remove the default buffer from the buffer list)
> 9. BufDelete       (deallocate the default buffer)
> 10. BufReadCmd      (read the contexts of demo.txt into the new buffer)
> 11. BufEnter        (activate the new buffer)
> 12. BufWinEnter     (activate the new buffer's window)i
> 13. InsertEnter     (swap into Insert mode)

It's still not entirely comprehensive (eg. no mention of `BufRead` aka `BufReadPost`, but I'm assuming it would come after `BufReadCmd`), but it's an excellent start.

One crucial missing piece of information though is how the `FileType` and `Syntax` autocmd events interact with this (assuming `filetype` and `syntax` are already on, and a new file is opened whose filetype and syntax are known to Vim).

Comment: This is only true when you're editing a single file.  Contrary to the popular belief, the order of applying `autocmd`s across multiple files is _not_ well-defined.  And even with a single file, the order has changed a few times with the version of Vim.  The problems this can (and do) cause for plugins have been discussed to death on vim_dev, and the overall design is not going to change in the predictible future.  As for getting a _comprehensive_ understanding, well, there are 139 occurrences of `apply_autocmds` in the sources for Vim 7.4.827.  Good luck with that.

Comment: @SatoKatsura This is the kind of expert opinion I was looking for, thanks! Is there some reference you can suggest to learn more about this (other than diving into Vim's sources)? Also, this might be entirely out of your area of interest, but do you have any idea if things are better defined in the 'Neovim'-land?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of any definitive reference.  `autocmd`s in Vim are a mess, I don't think it's actually _possible_ to write a definitive reference, except for a few simple cases.  I suppose everybody just settles for "usually works", and shrugs when it doesn't.  As for neovim, I personally have mixed feelings about the project.  I haven't looked at the code recently; I suppose you can get an answer on their issue tracker.

Comment: Also the term of "event" itself should subvert the idea of too fixed an order.

Answer (score 17):

To complete the @sundar answer:

You can log the order of the events simply with a logging function:

```
augroup EventLoggin
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufNewFile * call s:Log('BufNewFile')
  autocmd BufReadPre * call s:Log('BufReadPre')
  ...
  autocmd User * call s:Log('User')
augroup END

function! s:Log(eventName) abort
  silent execute '!echo '.a:eventName.' >> log'
endfunction
```

See the full file here: https://github.com/lervag/dotvim/blob/3aa56d621423540bfa26b330182b3e97ed4ee5e8/personal/plugin/log-autocmds.vim (NB: As the previous gist has disappeared, I've replaced the URL to Karl's plugin --Luc)

You can then `tail -f log` and you get a real-time autocommand events activity.

Comment: I made a simple plugin for this, see [here](https://github.com/lervag/dotvim/blob/master/bundle_local/log-autocmds/plugin/log-autocmds.vim).

Comment: Note that @KarlYngveLervåg has moved its plugin to [another path](https://github.com/lervag/dotvim/blob/master/personal/plugin/log-autocmds.vim). Thank Karl!

Comment: Thanks for noticing and commenting, Luc! (Note: I can't update my comment to fix the dead link, sorry!)

Answer (score 10):

This is the first result show up on google search about 'Vim event order'. So, i think it's worth providing the actual answer.

Using the command from @nobe4 answer, this is the result:

1. Opening a new file, insert letter 'a', write and quit.

```
Syntax
User
BufNewFile
FileType
Syntax
BufWinEnter
BufEnter
VimEnter
CursorMoved
FocusGained
InsertEnter
CursorHoldI
InsertCharPre
CursorMovedI
TextChangedI
InsertLeave
CursorMoved
CmdlineEnter
CmdlineChanged
CmdlineChanged
CmdlineLeave
BufWrite
BufWritePre
BufWritePost
QuitPre
ExitPre
BufWinLeave
BufUnload
VimLeavePre
BufNew
BufNew
VimLeave
```

2. Opening an existing file, append letter 'a', write and quit.

```
Syntax
User
BufReadPre
BufRead
BufReadPost
FileType
Syntax
BufWinEnter
BufEnter
VimEnter
CursorMoved
FocusGained
InsertEnter
CursorMovedI
InsertCharPre
CursorMovedI
TextChangedI
InsertLeave
CursorMoved
CmdlineEnter
CmdlineChanged
CmdlineChanged
CmdlineLeave
BufWrite
BufWritePre
BufWritePost
QuitPre
ExitPre
BufWinLeave
BufUnload
VimLeavePre
BufNew
BufNew
VimLeave
```

3. Opening a new file, write and quit.

```
Syntax
User
BufNewFile
FileType
Syntax
BufWinEnter
BufEnter
VimEnter
CursorMoved
FocusGained
CmdlineEnter
CmdlineChanged
CmdlineChanged
CmdlineLeave
BufWrite
BufWritePre
BufWritePost
QuitPre
ExitPre
BufWinLeave
BufUnload
VimLeavePre
BufNew
BufNew
VimLeave
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Some times `au BufEnter * if &ft=='help' | call My_func() | endif` or
`au BufEnter * if &buftype =='help' | call My_func() | endif`
is triggered even when I open My_any_FILE.zsh.

I guessed the reason was that 'filetype' or 'buftype' does not update until BufEnter finishes,
but from your conclusion, my guess seems wrong.

So why those 2 autocmds are  triggered even when I open My_any_FILE.zsh? Thx

Comment: What about launching Vim without arguments (i.e. `vim ` in the current directory)? It's the only missing option, I'd be interested to know that as well.