# autocmd BufAdd/BufCreate/BufNew aren't triggered for new, unnamed buffers (`:enew`)?

Tags: buffers, autocmd

I'm trying to set up an autocommand so that new, unnamed buffers are created with `ft=markdown`. Someone on SO [suggested the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5492283/4865822):

```
autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype == "" | setlocal ft=markdown | endif
```

which works great, but with which I have the following gripes:

1. this will `set ft=markdown` on **named** buffers, too (*e.g.,* `:e foo`), and
2. this will run every time I **switch to** (enter) the buffer, not just when it's first created — not a problem in practice, but not what I want to do in principle.

---

I've been working through the problem myself, but I can only get halfway there.

#### Success: the right `autocmd {pat}`

I've figured out that I can specify unnamed buffers by using a pair of empty curly braces (`{}`) in place of a filename pattern. That is,

```
autocmd VimEnter {} setlocal ft=markdown
```

will run on `$ vim`, but not on `$ vim foo`.

#### Failure: the right `autocmd {event}`

So now I'm looking for the right autocmd event: **one that is triggered on `:enew` or any other time a blank, unnamed buffer is added to the buffer list.** I've tried:

- `BufAdd`
- `BufCreate`
- `BufNew`

but none of these are triggered on `:enew`. I've tested this with the following autocommands:

```
autocmd BufAdd    * let b:foo = 'foo'
autocmd BufCreate * let b:foo = 'foo'
autocmd BufNew    * let b:foo = 'foo'
```

When I edit an existing file, `:echo exists('b:foo')` returns 1. When I `:enew`, it returns 0.

(To be clear, `BufEnter` still works, but I'm looking for one that only runs once.)

Is there an appropriate autocmd here, or should I file a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I was thinking of listening for `BufNewFile`, but this is not the right event. My mistake.

I had the confirmation thanks to a plugin given in another answer: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4493/what-is-the-order-of-winenter-bufenter-bufread-syntax-filetype-events

->

```
- BufNew -- 
- BufAdd -- 
- BufCreate -- 
- BufLeave -- /tmp/vim_log_autocommands
- BufEnter -- 
- BufWinEnter --
```

So, I've tested with your events:

```
aug Test
  au!
  au BufAdd    * :echom "Add ".expand('<amatch>')."--".bufnr('%') | let b:test = 1
  au BufCreate * :echom "Create ".expand('<amatch>')."--".bufnr('%') | let b:test = 1
  au BufNew    * :echom "New ".expand('<amatch>')."--".bufnr('%') | let b:test = 1
aug END
```

If you look closely, we see, first that the events are correctly triggered, and then that the buffer created isn't `bufnr('%')`. Hence `<amatch>` that is the proper way to proceed in many autocommands. This is hinted in the documentation:

> NOTE: When this autocommand is executed, the current buffer `%` may be different from the buffer being created `<afile>`.

If you go back to the buffer (corresponding to the number printed), you'll see that `b:test` is set to 1 over there. Actually you can expect the number of the new buffer to be `bufnr('$')+1`. Still, I wouldn't use `setbufvar()` as `getbufinfo(bufnr('%')+1)` is still empty.

That's why in the other answer, you were pointing to, they said to listen for `BufEnter` I guess. Instead, you'll have to mark the buffers you've already tested.

- Either you use an internal variable at your script level

  ```
  let s:been_there = {}
  aug FTOverride
    au! 
    " untested
    au BufEnter * if empty(&ft) && !get(s:been_there, bufnr('%'), 0) | set ft=markdown | let s:been_there[bufnr('%')] = 1 | endif
  aug END
  ```
- Or you use a buffer variable which will be visible by everyone

  ```
  ...
    " untested
    au BufEnter * if empty(&ft) && !get(b:, 'ft_overridden', 0) | set ft=markdown | let b:ft_overridden = 1 | endif
  ```

EDIT2: In a personal [plugin I'm maintaining](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/fixfilename.vim#L64), I've found another way to proceed. This time I listen for the root events. When triggered, I register an one-time-autocommand on `BufEnter`:

```
augroup auto_jump_to_line
  au!
  au BufNewFile,BufWinEnter *:* nested
        \ call lh#event#register_for_one_execution_at('BufEnter', function(s:getSNR('FixFilename')), 'auto_jump_to_line_1', expand('<afile>:t'))
augroup END
```

Where [`lh#event#register_for_one_execution_at()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/event.vim#L52) registers an autocommand that'll start by un-registering itself. I haven't checked in your case, but it may work. But choose only one autocommand among the 3 you've found.

Comment: Am I missing something? `BufNewFile` is only triggered when "starting to edit a file that doesn't exist" (as in `:e foo` but not `:enew`). Like the events mentioned above, `autocmd BufNewFile * let b:foo = 'foo'` does _not_ set the `b:foo` variable on `:enew` — at least in my experimentation. Is it different for you?

Comment: My mistake. I've though the events weren't triggered, while they do are. The problem is that the current buffer is not yet the buffer you've just created. I've completely rewritten my answer.

Comment: Whoa! Saw much of that in the helpdocs, but just wasn't getting it. Awesome explanation; definitely learned something new today.

Comment: @RyanLue, there be another way, see my new EDIT.

Comment: that's a mouthful, but very clever!