# How to view when events fire?

Tags: vimrc

Is there a verbose mode that shows when each of the various events fire? For example, I'm looking for something where I can use vim in the normal course of operations and see which events are being fired when, as opposed to just reading through the 70+ events and estimating theoretically when they occur. For example in the below mapping I have:

```
augroup SaveManualFolds
    autocmd!
    au BufWrite,VimLeave,BufLeave,BufWinLeave       ?*  mkview
    au BufWinEnter,BufRead                          ?*  loadview
augroup END
```

I'd like to see when `BufLeave` occurs, `BufWinLeave` etc.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4496/17449

Comment: In particular in the comment, I've given the updated link to Karl's plugin

Comment: @LucHermitte -- no, I want to log every single event -- those five listed are just examples. Basically, I'd like to use vim for about an hour or so and have a log in the left of my screen to see all the events firing and when they do...

Comment: @user938271 that answer looks much better.

Comment: @David542 the answer comes from the same Q/A, and when I speak about my comment, it's the one in the particular answer highlighted by user938271.

Comment: @LucHermitte got it, thanks. That is a bit of a verbose way to do it! I'll add in logs fo all the events now (seems like the github link for a previous function is no longer active on that question).