# Automatically resize window based on filetype

Tags: buffers, autocmd, vim-windows, filetype, help-system

I have a nifty autocommand in my `vimrc` that automatically maximizes any `:help` window:

```
augroup LargeHelpWindow
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWinEnter * if &l:buftype ==# 'help' | wincmd _ | endif
augroup END
```

This is really useful to optimize screen usage when using `:help` and it is based on buffer type. I would like to achieve the same for `:Man` so that I can comfortably view and navigate `man` documentation in Vim. However, since `:Man` buffers have `buftype` set to `nofile` and `filetype` set to `man`, I have to configure the resizing based on filetype. I have tried the following:

```
    autocmd Filetype man wincmd -
    autocmd BufWinEnter * if &l:filetype ==# 'man' | wincmd _ | endif
    autocmd WinEnter * if &l:filetype ==# 'man' | wincmd _ | endif
```

but this has not worked, i.e. `:Man` windows stay small and they need to be resized manually. I believe the reason for the failure of the autocommands above is the relative order of `BufWinEnter` and `WinEnter` vs `Filetype`. Unfortunately, the exact relative order [is not well documented](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4495/33382).

Is there a way to achieve automatic resizing of windows based on filetype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autocmd FileType man wincmd _` should work okay. Most probably you have a typo (e.g. in your post it's "dash" instead of "underscore").

Concerning auto-events, not all of them are bound to follow specific sequence. For example, `FileType` is triggered right after `'filetype'` option was set. For whatever reason.

Comment: I can confirm that the problem was indeed a dash `-` instead of an underscore `_`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I don't have the `:Man` command which you have presumably defined yourself, but this should work:

```
autocmd BufEnter * if &filetype ==# "man" | wincmd _ | endif
```

Comment: Thanks! This works too. I have decided to accept the other answer because it was a bit more informative as to why my solution didn't work, but this also fixes the problem. Regarding `:Man`, in order to use it you have to source the appropriate plugin first: `runtime ftplugin/man.vim`,

Comment: No worries, glad it worked out and thanks for the the information on `:Man`, I was not aware of that.