# How do I use github copilot in NvChad?

Tags: neovim, plugin, nvchad

I've written the following in my custom folder, and I've run `:PackerSync` followed by `:Copilot setup`, but I get an error: `E492: Not an editor command: Copilot setup`.

Do I need to clone [github/copilot](https://github.com/github/copilot.vim) somewhere or does Packer do it automatically? How do I configure it on NvChad?

`custom/chadrc.lua`

```
local plugin_conf = require "custom.plugins.configs"

M.plugins = {
   user = userPlugins,
   override = {
      ["hrsh7th/nvim-cmp"] = plugin_conf.cmp,
   },
}
```

`custom/plugins.lua`

```
return {
   ["github/copilot.vim"] = {
      config = function()
         vim.cmd [[
            let g:copilot_no_tab_map = v:true
         ]]
      end,
   },
   ["hrsh7th/cmp-copilot"] = {
      after = "nvim-cmp",
   },
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to add copilot.lua in `custom/plugins.lua` using something like this:

```lua
local overrides = require("custom.configs.overrides")

local plugins = {
  ...
  {
    "zbirenbaum/copilot.lua",
    -- Lazy load when event occurs. Events are triggered
    -- as mentioned in:
    -- https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4495/20389
    event = "InsertEnter",
    -- You can also have it load at immediately at
    -- startup by commenting above and uncommenting below:
    -- lazy = false
    opts = overrides.copilot,
  },
  ...
}
...

return plugins
```

Then you can override the default configuration in `custom/configs/overrides.lua`:

```lua
local M = {}

...

M.copilot = {
  -- Possible configurable fields can be found on:
  -- https://github.com/zbirenbaum/copilot.lua#setup-and-configuration
  suggestion = {
    auto_trigger = true,
  },
}

...

return M
```

You should be able to call `:Copilot auth` after you go into Insert mode once (since that's how we defined it to lazy load in `plugins.lua` in the above example).